# Let $\bar{x_0}\in D$ if $f$ is continually differentiable in $\bar{x_0}$ then $f$ is differentiable in $\bar{x_0}$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $D\subset\mathbb{R}$ a open set, $f:D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ a function and $\bar{x_0}\in D$ if $f$ is continually differentiable in $\bar{x_0}$ then $f$ is differentiable in $\bar{x_0}$

Here is the proof of the theorem, but i don't understand the red parts.
[image: The proof]

Questions:

1- How i know $f$ fulfill with the hyptohesis of mean value theorem (I tried to see this but i cannot) and i dont understand very well how he apply mean value theorem here.

2- Why $lim_{\bar{}h\rightarrow \bar{0}}\bar{v_k}(\bar{h})=\bar{x_0} $

3- Why that two symbols are equal (arrows)?

4-I don't see very clear the inequality.

Thanks for his help.

Answer (score 1):

I manage to say something about number three and four, for one and two the notations are messy and I am not sure neither:

3) $\left<\nabla f(x_{0}),h\right>=\left<\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_{k}}(x_{0})e_{k},\sum_{k=1}^{n}h_{k}e_{k}\right>=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}h_{k}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_{k}}(x_{0})$ by the orthogonality of $\{e_{k}\}_{k=1}^{n}$.

4) We have $\left|\dfrac{h_{k}}{\|h\|}\right|\leq\dfrac{\|h\|}{\|h\|}=1$.

Comment: Thanks man, very grateful.